Apt suggesting auto remove of important packages
This comes up when i try to sudo apt upgrade.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  atop bmon cabextract ccze dctrl-tools deltarpm dnf-data gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gpaste-1.0 gir1.2-gsound-1.0
  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0 gpaste htop hwdata icu-devtools jp2a libasound2-dev libatomic1:i386
  libblkid-dev libbsd0:i386 libcomps0 libconfuse-common libconfuse2 libdbus-1-dev libdecor-0-dev libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdnf2 libdnf2-common libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libegl-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi-dev libffi8:i386 libfsverity0 libgbm-dev
  libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles-dev libgles1 libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libgpaste13 libgpod-common
  libgpod4 libgsoap-2.8.117 libicu-dev libicu70:i386 libio-pty-perl libipc-run-perl liblirc-client0 libllvm15:i386 liblzf1 libmd0:i386 libmodulemd2 libmount-dev libmspack0
  libnvidia-compute-535:i386 libnvidia-decode-535:i386 libnvidia-encode-535:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386 libopengl-dev libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre16-3 libpcre2-dev libpcre2-posix3
  libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpfm4 libqt5designer5 libqt5help5 libqt5location5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5positioningquick5 libqt5qml5 libqt5qmlmodels5
  libqt5quick5 libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5serialport5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5texttospeech5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webengine-data
  libqt5webengine5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5websockets5 libqt5x11extras5 libqt5xml5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libre2-9 librepo0 librpm9 librpmbuild9
  librpmio9 librpmsign9 libsdl1.2debian libselinux1-dev libsensors5:i386 libsepol-dev libsgutils2-2 libsndio-dev libsolv1 libsolvext1 libstdc++6:i386 libtime-duration-perl
  libudev-dev libunbound8 liburing2 libutempter0 libwayland-bin libwayland-dev libwireshark16 libwiretap13 libwsutil14 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
  libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxkbcommon-dev libxml2:i386 libxml2-dev libxnvctrl0 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libz3-4 libz3-dev llvm-14 llvm-14-runtime moreutils plocate
  python3-pip-whl python3-setuptools-whl qtspeech5-speechd-plugin rpm-common run-one screen-resolution-extra sqlite3 sshfs tmux tree xsel

but it contains the tools I need such as htop atop tree sqlite3 etc. i only ran few scripts in the past which contained apt remove and those are
LANG=C snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |     while read snapname revision; do         snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision";     done

And uninstalling pycharm professional not sure what removing triggered this.
PS. all the tools given are working fine I just wanna know what possible library/package may have triggered this

Pro Tip: Avoid the use of scripts to remove software packages. They lead to precisely this kind of self-inflicted problem. Use apt yourself. It's not difficult. And always review the list of proposed removals before agreeing.

The script you provide does not actually have an apt remove command in it and deals with snaps, which has nothing to do with apt. Please edit your question and tell what you really did.


Check that you have the ubuntu-desktop metapackage installed.
The output clearly tells you if it's [installed].
$ apt list ubuntu-desktop
Listing... Done
ubuntu-desktop/mantic-updates,now 1.524.1 amd64 [installed]

If not installed, then re-install it. That will clear up most of the list.
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop


Applications that are not dependencies of ubuntu-desktop must be remarked. This includes htop, sqlite3, and others on your revised much-smaller list.

Apt Marking is how apt tracks which packages are pulled in as dependencies (auto) and which packages are chosen by a human (manual). Only auto packages are eligible for auto-removal. If a key tool like htop or sqlite is eligible for autoremoval, then it has been mis-marked.

It's as simple as...
sudo apt-mark manual htop sqlite3 package3 package4 packageN

Don't remark dependencies. Only the top package should be manual. Each tree of dependencies should remain auto.


